# Best way to use multi dimensions arrays for voxels

Tags: multidimensional-array, rust

Im currently making a voxel tool for godot with rust and to store the data of the voxels i think i need a multi dimension array to get easily the data of the voxels, but is so hard to get the voxels in the array and i really dont know if i just use `ndarray` lib or i use `vec![vec![vec![etc.]]]`.

So how i should store the data of the voxels in an array that is easy to get voxels in a 3D environment?

Comment: in every language the best is to avoid it. I believe ndarray is implement as one vector but some operation are discouraged.

Comment: well i need multi dimensions arrays because im making a voxel tool for godot using rust

Comment: I think we need more details about your use case to say what is the best way for you to implement multidimensional arrays. For example, what do you dislike about `ndarray`? Also, you don't need anything per se to implement multidimensional arrays, you can just put an array inside another array [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=75fd33a8d9b7ca27a97432db8ada8f60) – whether or not this fits your use case is of course another question.

Comment: >"I think we need more details about your use case"
ok, im gonna update the question

Comment: If you need any degree of speed you should not nest `Vec`tors. Write a wrapper around a Vec that will convert `(x, y ,z)` coordinates to a index into inner Vec.

Comment: good idea, i think i will make a function called: `get_voxel` and it will do a loop to get the index and then use the index to return the voxel type